# Excluded properties via BindAttribute and ModelValidator in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, binding

Good evening,

I'm having trouble with model binding and validation but I don't know whether it's a normal behavior : the problem is that, is spite of BindAttribute (with his property Excluded correctly filled), the excluded properties are validated but not removed in the ModelState dictionary... so I get errors in my views... concerning an excluded property! Doh!

So, is there a way to get the "non-excluded-properties" list, directly in my model validator so I can tell my validation service not to validate excluded properties?

Here are the validator provider and the validator itself (just an internal wrapper around the great FluentValidator)

```
internal sealed class ValidationProvider : ModelValidatorProvider {
    private readonly IValidationFactory _validationFactory;

    public ValidationProvider(IValidationFactory validationFactory) {
        _validationFactory = validationFactory;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context) {
        if (metadata.ModelType != null) {
            IValidationService validationService;
            if (_validationFactory.TryCreateServiceFor(metadata.ModelType, out validationService)) {
                yield return new ValidationAdapter(metadata, context, validationService);
            }
        }
    }

    private sealed class ValidationAdapter : ModelValidator {
        private readonly IValidationService _validationService;

        internal ValidationAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata,
            ControllerContext controllerContext,
            IValidationService validationService)
            : base(metadata, controllerContext) {
            _validationService = validationService;
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container) {
            if (Metadata.Model != null) {
                IEnumerable<ValidationFault> validationFaults;
                if (!_validationService.TryValidate(Metadata.Model, out validationFaults)) {
                    return validationFaults.Select(fault => new ModelValidationResult {
                        MemberName = fault.PropertyInfo.Name,
                        Message = fault.FaultedRule.Message
                    });
                }
            }

            return Enumerable.Empty<ModelValidationResult>();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the action :

```
public class MyModel {
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test([Bind(Exclude = "Test")] MyModel model) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        ...
    }

    return View();
}
```

*Here, I get errors for excluded "Test" property... Huh!*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who want avoiding the "validate everything then delete unwanted properties" scenario, I've extended the default model binder using a nested model metadata provider (because the "Properties" property of ModelMetadata is readonly...) :

So, now, I can only validate "non-excluded properties" :

```
public class OldWayValidationBinder : DefaultModelBinder {
    private readonly ModelMetadataProvider _metadataProvider;

    public ValidationBinder(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider) {
        _metadataProvider = metadataProvider;
    }

    protected ModelMetadata CreateModelMetadata(ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        var metadataProvider = new ModelMetadataProviderAdapter(
            _metadataProvider, bindingContext.PropertyFilter);

        return new ModelMetadata(metadataProvider,
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ContainerType,
            () => bindingContext.ModelMetadata.Model,
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ModelType,
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata.PropertyName);
    }

    protected override void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        base.OnModelUpdated(controllerContext, new ModelBindingContext(bindingContext) {
            ModelMetadata = CreateModelMetadata(bindingContext)
        });
    }

    private sealed class ModelMetadataProviderAdapter : ModelMetadataProvider {
        private readonly ModelMetadataProvider _innerMetadataProvider;
        private readonly Predicate<string> _propertyFilter;

        internal ModelMetadataProviderAdapter(
            ModelMetadataProvider innerMetadataProvider,
            Predicate<string> propertyFilter) {
            _innerMetadataProvider = innerMetadataProvider;
            _propertyFilter = propertyFilter;
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ModelMetadata> GetMetadataForProperties(object container, Type containerType) {
            return _innerMetadataProvider.GetMetadataForProperties(container, containerType)
                .Where(metadata => _propertyFilter(metadata.PropertyName));
        }

        public override ModelMetadata GetMetadataForProperty(Func<object> modelAccessor, Type containerType, string propertyName) {
            return _innerMetadataProvider.GetMetadataForProperty(modelAccessor, containerType, propertyName);
        }

        public override ModelMetadata GetMetadataForType(Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType) {
            return _innerMetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(modelAccessor, modelType);
        }
    }
}

internal sealed class ValidationProvider : ModelValidatorProvider {
    private readonly IValidationFactory _validationFactory;

    public ValidationProvider(IValidationFactory validationFactory) {
        _validationFactory = validationFactory;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context) {
        if (metadata.ModelType != null) {
            IValidationService validationService;
            if (_validationFactory.TryCreateServiceFor(metadata.ModelType, out validationService)) {
                yield return new ModelValidatorAdapter(metadata, context, validationService);
            }
        }
    }

    private sealed class ModelValidatorAdapter : ModelValidator {
        private readonly IValidationService _validationService;

        internal ValidationAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata,
            ControllerContext controllerContext,
            IValidationService validationService)
            : base(metadata, controllerContext) {
            _validationService = validationService;
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container) {
            if (Metadata.Model != null) {
                IEnumerable<ValidationFault> validationFaults;
                var validatableProperties = Metadata.Properties.Select(metadata => Metadata.ModelType.GetProperty(metadata.PropertyName));
                if (!_validationService.TryValidate(Metadata.Model, validatableProperties, out validationFaults)) {
                    return validationFaults.Select(fault => new ModelValidationResult {
                        MemberName = fault.PropertyInfo.Name,
                        Message = fault.FaultedRule.Message
                    });
                }
            }

            return Enumerable.Empty<ModelValidationResult>();
        }
    }
}
```

**Nonetheless, I believe this scenario must be present as an option in MVC. At least, the unbound properties list should be given as a parameter of ModelValidatorProvider's GetValidators method!**

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behavior. This change (always doing whole-model validation) was made late in the MVC 2 ship cycle based on customer feedback (and the principle of least surprise).

More information:

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: And I suppose there is no way to get the "excluded-properties" list directly in the validator?

Comment: No, your three options generally are:

1. Ensure you have valid data in the unbound properties
2. Use a view-specific model so you don't have this problem
3. Remove the ViewState entries for the properties you don't care about

Comment: Hum... having valid data in unbound "navigation" properties is not always easy with complex rules... I wanted to stay away from DTOs and I believe ViewState editing could lead to unelegant controllers. Nonetheless, I suppose achieving this job (editing ViewState) could be easily done by overriding the default model binder?

Comment: Sorry, I meant ModelState. You should be able to say ModelState["propertyname"].Errors.Clear() or something similar.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at the DefaultModelBinder code tomorrow, in order to see whether I can do that directly in the model binder, to keep my controllers clean.

Comment: The model binder is definitely where validation takes place. We previously used to have it only validate properties which were bound; it shouldn't be too hard to revert to that behavior. Let me know if you need any pointers. bradwils at microsoft dot com.

Comment: Thank you very much! Please tell me whether I'm in the right direction with the snippet I posted. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the "old behavior" can be easily recovered by overriding the OnModelUpdating method of the DefaultModelBinder. Please point me in the right direction whether it's not the good way to achieve that :

```
internal sealed class OldWayModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder {
    protected override void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        foreach (var validationResult in ModelValidator.GetModelValidator(bindingContext.ModelMetadata, controllerContext).Validate(null)) {
            string subPropertyName = CreateSubPropertyName(bindingContext.ModelName, validationResult.MemberName);
            if (bindingContext.PropertyFilter(subPropertyName)) {
                if (bindingContext.ModelState.IsValidField(subPropertyName)) {
                    bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(subPropertyName, validationResult.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(however, the fact that the IsValidField method returns true if a given property is faulted is a little bit strange or there is something I don't understand!)

Comment: Note that this code has several issues when it comes to validating child classes of the view model. More precisely, you cannot use bindingContext.PropertyFilter(subPropertyName) for that in all cases. This will work instead though :  if (((controllerContext.HttpContext).Request).Form[subPropertyName] != null || bindingContext.ModelName == subPropertyName)

Comment: Yep, you're right, this little piece of code only works for simple models and should not be used for complex models. That said, your workaround is not perfect either as it doesn't rely on value providers and should not be used with custom ones. Moreover, as it directly picks in Request.Form collection, you can't validate properties contained in the url, as an example.